# Looping over an objects indices while performing an operation / calculation using Animation Nodes - attached blend file

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes, looping, quaternion

I'm having trouble looping over an objects (the cylinder) polygon indices while performing an operation / calculation on them.

I created an animation in Octave, (and the calculations are correct I've also verified that the calculations in Animation Nodes are the same). I'm just having problems looping over the indices to produce the same animation using animation nodes that I have in Octave 5.x. See attached animation created in Octave 5.x of how it should look. I've also included the blend file and an image of the node.

**The new calculations are generated / how the object should be transformed is controlled by the timeline which represent the number of "degrees" it should rotate.**

**Please note: I know it looks like a simple rotation but it isn't, it's visualizing / showing different quaternion calculations.**

[image: Animated quaternion]

**The entire node setup:**
[image: The entire node setup:]

**The section that does the calculations:**
[image: The section that does the calculations:]

**Animated calculations which verify the math is correct** 
[image: Animated Calculations]

**The section with the vertices I'm trying to loop over:**
[image: The section with the vertices I'm trying to loop over]

I tried using the Object transforms output node, but that does simple rotations **I'm trying to have finer control and performing mathematical operations on the indices seems to be the way to go**. I'm just having trouble combining the calculations and the looping over all the indices together. **I'm trying to get the "mathematical morphing" seen in the animation above using calculations.**

[image]

Ps: I'm using Blender 2.83 I've also included the texture file below if needed.
[image: Texture file]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109387/discussion-on-question-by-rick-t-looping-over-an-objects-indices-while-performin).